# English fraction ex) one third etc

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

I know when comparing two things using multiplicative numerals, some usages like the following sentences are possible.

> This book is *twice* the price of that book.
>   This book is *twice* as expensive as that book.

I wonder if this rule also applies to fractions such as one-third or one-tenth.

> This book is *one-third* the price of that book.
>   This book is *one-third* as expensive as that book.

Comment: You're exactly right. If one book costs $10, that means that another book that is _one-third_ as expensive (or _one-third of_ the price) would cost $3.33.

Comment: The hyphen is discretionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your example sentences are fine.  You can also say "a third" or "a tenth":

> This book is **a third** of the price of the other book.
>
> If you go to my brother's shop, you can get that outfit for less than **a tenth** of the retail price.